# check if file has an appropriate suffix bash

Tags: bash

FileI wrote this

```
function copyFile() {
    local source=$1
    set -x
    for dictionary in $DICT_PATH; do
        dictname=$(basename $dictionary)
        dict_prefix=${dictname%%.*}
        TARGET="gs://bucket/files"
        gsutil cp -r $dictionary  $TARGET
    done
}
```

I want to add a condition to copy only files whose termination is .json or .xml

I wrote this

```
function copyFile() {
    local source=$1

    set -x
    for dictionary in $DICT_PATH; do
        dictname=$(basename $dictionary)
        if [[ ${dictname: -5} == ".json"  ]] || [[ ${dictname: -5} == ".xml"  ]] ; then
            dict_prefix=${dictname%%.*}
            TARGET="gs://bucket/files"
            gsutil cp -r $dictionary  $TARGET
        fi
    done
}
```

but this didn't work. Any idea how to fix this please.

Comment: Pattern matching would be simpler: `if [[ $dictname = *.json || $dictname = *.xml ]]; then`. That would prevent the possibility of using `-5` when you mean `-4`, as with your `xml` check.

Answer (score 1):

`xml` is a shorter string than `json`, so your suffix is too long to compare equal to `.xml`.

```
#                                                      -4, not -5
if [[ ${dictname: -5} == ".json"  ]] || [[ ${dictname: -4} == ".xml"  ]] ; then
```

You can avoid this mistake by using the much simpler pattern-matching facilities of `[[ ... ]]`.

```
if [[ $dictname = *.json || $dictname = *.xml ]]; then
```

or even a POSIX-compatible `case` statement:

```
case $dictname in
  *.json|*.xml) 
        dict_prefix=${dictname%%.*}
        TARGET="gs://bucket/files"
        gsutil cp -r "$dictionary"  "$TARGET"
        ;;
sac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the file extension as `${filename#*.}`.

This should give something like following,

```
ext=${dictname#*.}
if [[ $ext == 'json']] || [[ $ext == 'xml' ]]; then
    # code 
fi
```

Or, use regular expressions,

```
if [[ $dictname =~ (json|xml)$ ]]; then
    # code
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filetype=${dictionary##*.}
if [[ "$filetype" == "json" ]] || [[ "$filetype" == "xml" ]]; then
    echo YES
fi
```